# connecting… for infinity time

Tags: server, httpd

I have website working fine before. But now its not able to connect to the server(I believe that is the problem).  But its strange that the message **not able to connect to the server** is not coming and its keep **connecting...** for infinite time.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

---

Here are some of the useful details about the status of the server.

Application starts when server wakes up are:

```
cd /etc/init.d/
```

[image]
Application server running in my server :

[image]

`Traceroute`:
[image]

Comment: Are other users affected as well? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: It's possible, the problem, is in the application. Read the application log to find any kind of error.